# Spring Tool Suite strange behaviour for content assist

Tags: spring-tool-suite, content-assist

I have a demo spring batch project in STS.
It has strange behaviour about content assist in xml file configurations.
It is working in one of following file **job.xml**  and **not** working im **context.xml**.
What may be the problem?

`job.xml` - Content Assist working

[image]

`context.xml` - Content Assist **NOT** working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the `jobs.xml` file is opened and edited with the `Spring Config Editor` whereas the `content.xml` is edited with a standard XML editor. Try `Open With...` on the `context.xml` file and choose the `Spring Config Editor`.

Comment: No both was opened with `Spring Config Editor`, **changing name** `context.xml` to `my-context.xml` solved my problem